# how to get friends who like my topic

Tags: php, mysql

i have **users** table
has **id** field
and the friendship table **frienduser** has **friend1id** or **friend2id** according who sent a request to whom first
and likes table | **thread_id** - **userid**
i want select from users the persons who are my friends and liked the topic

Comment: I see some spelling mistakes there `users` and `frienduser` etc..

Comment: I can't edit but I assume that is `users` table. Are you asking for help with the php or mysql? Either way, more code required

Comment: looks like a pure mysql thing to me, and more schema would be nice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ugly part of this is the fact that the **frienduser** table could link on either ID. I think the simplest way around this would be with a union.

```
/* Case 1: My ID is friend1id, my friend is friend2id */
select u2.*
    from users u1
        inner join frienduser f
            on u1.id = f.friend1id
        inner join users u2
            on f.friend2id = u2.id
        inner join likes l
            on u2.id = l.userid
    where u1.id = @MyUserId
        and l.threadid = @MyThreadId
union
/* Case 2: My ID is friend2id, my friend is friend1id */
select u2.*
    from users u1
        inner join frienduser f
            on u1.id = f.friend2id
        inner join users u2
            on f.friend1id = u2.id
        inner join likes l
            on u2.id = l.userid
    where u1.id = @MyUserId
        and l.threadid = @MyThreadId
```

Answer (score 1):

[There you go.](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)